# Edit action for file upload

Tags: zend-framework2

Following [tutorial](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/), im able to create file upload well, and as per zend tutorial, editAction is almost same as the Add action.

If I dont add file upload code in editAction it works fine, but after adding file upload, shows error in exchangearray()

Cannot use object of type \Model\CompanyReport as array in \module\report\src\report\Model\CompanyReport.php on line 20

Here is model file

```
public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    <-this is line number 20->$this->id       = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->title  = (isset($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
    $this->company  = (isset($data['company'])) ? $data['company'] : null;
    $this->sector  = (isset($data['sector'])) ? $data['sector'] : null;
    $this->report_date  = (isset($data['report_date'])) ? $data['report_date'] : null;
    $this->report_file = (isset($data['report_file'])) ? $data['report_file'] : null;

}
```

and below is the editAction code

```
public function editAction(){
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!$id) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('companyreport', array(
            'action' => 'add'
        ));
    }

    // Get the Album with the specified id.  An exception is thrown
    // if it cannot be found, in which case go to the index page.
    try {
        $companyreport = $this->getCompanyReportTable()->getCompanyReport($id);
    }
    catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('companyreport', array(
            'action' => 'index'
        ));
    }

    $form  = new CompanyReportForm();
    $form->bind($companyreport);
    $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $companyreport = new CompanyReport();
        $form->setInputFilter($companyreport->getInputFilter());

        $nonFile = $request->getPost()->toArray();
        $File    = $this->params()->fromFiles('report_file');

        $data    = array_merge_recursive(
                    $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),          
                   $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
               );
         $form->setData($data);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $size = new Size(array('min'=>500000)); //minimum bytes filesize

            $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
            //validator can be more than one...
            $adapter->setValidators(array($size), $File['name']);

            if (!$adapter->isValid()){
                $dataError = $adapter->getMessages();
                $error = array();
                foreach($dataError as $key=>$row)
                {
                    $error[] = $row;
                } //set formElementErrors
                $form->setMessages(array('report_file'=>$error ));
            } else {

                $adapter->setDestination(dirname(__DIR__).'/company_reports');
                if ($adapter->receive($File['name'])) {
                    $companyreport->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                    $this->getCompanyReportTable()->saveCompanyReport($companyreport);

                // Redirect to list of albums
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('companyreport');
                }
            } 
        } 
    }

    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'form' => $form,
    );
}
```

**Please suggest editAction for file upload.**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a matter of the file upload code. You've binded the entity to the form:

```
$form->bind($companyreport);
```

When `$form->setData($data)` is executed, the form binds the posted data with the entity. This means that `$form->getData()` will return the entity filled with the all that data. That's what the error says, it's returning an entity (`CompanyReport`), not an array.

The code executed for the `$form->getData()` (`Zend\Form\Form\getData()`) is:

```
    //IF YOU BIND, $this->object WILL BE THE ENTITY, SO IT'LL RETURN IT    
    if (($flag !== FormInterface::VALUES_AS_ARRAY) && is_object($this->object)) {
        return $this->object;
    }

    //OTHERWISE IT'LL RETURN AN ARRAY WITH POSTED DATA
    $filter = $this->getInputFilter();

    if ($flag === FormInterface::VALUES_RAW) {
        return $filter->getRawValues();
    }

    return $filter->getValues();
```

If you want to use your `exchangeArray` function, you could pass to it the merged array `$data`. But it's unnecessary, when you bind a form to an entity the 'exchangeArray job' is done by the form itself.